# How to break out of the promise chain for a subsequent method after calling an Apex method in LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, promises

getInformation() calls Apex imperatively which in turn makes an external callout. Once the data is received, I want doSomething() method to run. But I don't want doSomething() to run within the promise chain callstack. They are supposed to be sequential but separate. Also, this way errors in doSomething() isn't going to be catched by getInformation().

```
getInformation() {
    getDetails({ recordId: this.recordId })
      .then((data) => {
        this.parsedResponse = JSON.parse(data.responseBody);

          this.doSomething();

      })
      .catch((error) => {
        this.isLoading = false;
        console.log("ERROR: ", error);

      });
  }
```

The only idea I can think of is wrapping it in setTimeout but I am not sure if it's a good practice.

```
   setTimeout(() => {
          this.doSomething();
      }, 0);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [async await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) combination here.
`async/await` syntax is fully supported by LWC

```
async getInformation() {
    try {
        let getDetailsReponse = await getDetails({recordId: this.recordId})
        this.parsedResponse = JSON.parse(getDetailsReponse.responseBody);
        this.doSomething();
    } catch (exp){
        console.error(exp);
    }
}
```